Live Solana Token Data
I'm trying to find a better method to get live, accurate and fast token data.
I've been using Raydium API for the better part of the last 3 months however, a lot if not all my new pairs initially take about 3-5 minutes if im lucky after the launch to get a response that's useable from Raydium and its by no means effective enough in my opinion.
Im running a bot thats scans new pairs and monitors the token data such as initial liquidity value (usd), token price, and a few other things that i can grab fast from solscan.
I can't seem to find anything on solscan api to get the liquidity data im hoping to use or the "price" of 1 token.
Any help would be greatly appreciated
I dont want to use birdseye for any of this because they limit to 5mil cu a month which wont be enough for the longterm use of my project.
